# Asus N53SV - upgrading bios without battery

Tags: laptop, bios, battery

I want to upgrade BIOS, my battery seems to be broken as I am getting communicates that battery must be replaced or have at least 20%. So I cant do it using EasyFlash in Bios. I downloaded Afudos but examples shows that it uses ROM files and newest bios for my Asus is in this format: N53SVAS.215.

Cant I use Afudos of maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER: I do not recommend doing this for obvious reasons. If your machine loses power midway through a BIOS update, you're likely left with a brick!**

Firstly - ask yourself if you really need to apply a BIOS update? Why do you 'want' to? Is there actually something wrong with the machine fixed by the latest update?

> 1.Show system serial number on setup menu
>
> 2.Add New CPU function support
>
> 3.Update CPU microcode
>
> 4.Fix sometimes system can't boot after press power button.
>
> 5.Update EC firmware

I can see 4 being an irritation, but is it worth risking a completely dead system for?

If you still want to go ahead, try this at your own risk.

The download page for [your machine](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/271/0/6/Gjsm3Kp4pjz9iJM1/30/) lists the bios utility to use as WinFlash.

You can run this with a command line argument, usually `/f` or `/forceit` to bypass checks.

Comment: Ok I will go now for a new battery. I must upgrad bios as it is the last idea I have as for the error: A disk read error occurred Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart. This error is after cloning my WIndows7 to new SSD Crucial BX100. I am trying 2 days to start the system without results.

Answer (score 3):

I have updated bios for a ASUS F75A (2012) without battery.

1) Download the new bios (for me X75A1AS.412) and copy it on USB key (FAT32).

2) Start and enter bios, then in bios menu : "Advanced" -> "Start Easy Flash"

3) When the system will display that you can not update the bios because there is no battery, on your keyboard you enter "risky"

Comment: Confirmed for N56VZ. Just type "risky" on your keyboard after entering easy flash in BIOS.