# upgrade BIOS on Asus without EasyFlash and WinFlash

Tags: bios, battery, asus-laptop, freedos

I have an Asus notebook ([model F200MA](https://www.asus.com/pt/supportonly/F200MA)), running GNU/Linux (Debian Stretch) with a non-functional battery and I want to update the BIOS.  How can I update the BIOS without WinFlash and EasyFlash?

- I'm not using Windows so I can't use the WinFlash utility from Asus
- the battery does not work so I can't use EasyFlash (it requires a battery charged to at least 20%)

I am used to update BIOS using FreeDOS. This works fine when the BIOS update are an executable.  However, the BIOS updates from Asus appear as just data files (I have downloaded [X200MAAS.506](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X200MA/X200MAAS506.zip)).

**Edit**: the reason to update the BIOS is so that it recognises the battery. The battery (which is non-removable) has always worked fine. When I changed OS, it stopped working. This is not a Linux issue, even after reinstalling Windows the battery issue remains. The reported fix is to update the BIOS which fixes it until changing OS again.

Comment: You don't....`ASUS EZ Flash` is the solution you use, if you are not using Windows, to update the firmware on your machine.

Comment: @Ramhound EasyFlash does not work because it does not see the battery. And the reason to update the BIOS is so that it identifies the battery which I'm pretty sure is actually working fine.

Comment: You are out of luck.  ASUS does not provide an executable, for this purpose, that doesn't require the use of Windows.  If you have reinstalled Windows, then you are able to use the provided method, I suggest you do that.

Comment: You don't have to reinstall windows, and you can use Winflash with the /forceit switch command to bypass the battery check from a Windows command line.  Putting in a Windows disk and using its repair or recovery options to dump you to a command prompt should get you what you need.

Answer (score 9):

I found a post having the very same problem with the same computer model, and **I finally found a solution which worked for me**. You should confirm if this resolves your problem as it did for me but just in case, I wanted to add as an answer.

When you start **Easy Flash** to upgrade the BIOS and it tells you that you need a battery charged at least 20%, just type on your keyboard the word "**risky**", and it'll bypass the battery check, allowing you to flash the new firmware file.

**Warning:** If the firmware is in the middle of applying the update and the device powers off, then you could brick the machine you are flashing the firmware.

> I have updated bios for a ASUS F75A (2012) without battery.
>
> 1. Download the new bios (for me X75A1AS.412) and copy it on USB key
>      (FAT32).
> 2. Start and enter bios, then in bios menu : "Advanced" -> "Start Easy
>      Flash"
> 3. When the system will display that you can not update the bios
>      because there is no battery, on your keyboard you enter "risky"
>
> Source:
>   [Asus N53SV - upgrading bios without battery](https://superuser.com/questions/1017157/asus-n53sv-upgrading-bios-without-battery)

Comment: Confirmed that this worked for me with ASUS R500A with bad battery.

Comment: Confirmed for the X200MA Asus notebook

Comment: Holy cow, this is amazing.  Confirmed on an ASUS Q551LNB!

Comment: This doesn't work for me with AMI Version 206 on the Asus ROG 751. Typing "risky" doesn't do anything. :(